# How can I make a div's visibility depend on an object's scrollHeight and height properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've implemented some divs that will scroll  up and down on mouseover.  If there is no scroll, however, I'd like to make these divs disappear.  I've attempted to do this by comparing the scrollHeight of the container with the real height of the container.  If they match, I'd like the 'visibility' property of the hover scrolling divs to be 'hidden'.

Here's my code. What am I missing?

```
$(function () {
if ($('#container').scrollHeight() == $('#container').height()) {
    $('.HoverScrollUp,#HoverScrollDown').css('visibility': 'hidden');
    }
})
```

(And yes, .HoverScrollUp is supposed to be a class, and not an ID).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

> scrollHeight is a property of the DHTML object model which was first
>   introduced by MSIE. It is referred to as the height of an element's
>   physical scrolling view. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight)

Since it's a property and not a method, calling `.scrollHeight()` doesn't work. You have to access it like a property per qwertymk's example. Note it won't work in IE7. I'd recommend not using it altogether.

There's also a syntax problem with `.css('visibility': 'hidden');` The `:` should be a `,`

Try the following in place of `scrollHeight`:

```
if ($('#HoverScrollDown').outerHeight() < $('#container').innerHeight()) {
    $('.HoverScrollUp,#HoverScrollDown').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}else if ($('#HoverScrollDown').outerWidth() < $('#container').innerWidth()) {
    $('.HoverScrollUp,#HoverScrollDown').css('visibility', 'hidden');
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/tN2r5/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure it addresses my situation, though.  I need to compare #container's visible height versus its height with scroll.  If there is no difference, I need to hide #HoverScrollDown and .HoverScrollUp. The height of #HoverScrollDown and .HoverScrollUp shouldn't relate. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I probably misunderstood your problem. Did you get it working per qwertymk's suggestion?

Comment: Thank you for taking such an interest.  No, I didn't.  It seems like it should do the trick, but for some reason it's not.  It very well could be something I'm overlooking in my own code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the if statement:

```
if ($('#container')[0].scrollHeight === $('#container').height())
```

Although you should be caching the query:

```
$(function () {
    var $container = $('#container');

    if ($container[0].scrollHeight === $container.height()) {
        $('.HoverScrollUp,#HoverScrollDown').css('visibility': 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Don't ask me why this is, I had the same problem until I saw that this worked, maybe it's a bug in jQuery?

Comment: `$('#container')[0]` returns a DOM element which has access to the DHTML object model property `.scrollHeight`, whereas the jQuery object does not because no such jQuery property exists.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and thank you for the clarification, @alpaca lips.  I've attempted this, and it is unconditionally removes the two hover divs.  Doesn't seem to care if the scroll-able height is different from the visible height.  Seems like it should work, too...